# How Draw Watermark Text Tiles to Fit Image

Tags: c#, .net, string, draw

I want to draw a text string in C# .NET 4.5 on an image and calculate the text positions based on the number of tiles.
Let's say for 1 tile to draw the string in the middle and for 4 tiles to draw 2 tiles on a row and so on...

How can I calculate the text positions for any given tiles number ?

[image]

I have this function which I need to modify:

```
private void DrawTiledWatermark(Graphics grPhoto, String strText, Font fnt, Brush brush, int nNumTiles)
    {
        StringFormat StrFormat = new StringFormat();
        StrFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

        for (int nCurrentWatermark = 0; nCurrentWatermark < nNumTiles; nNumWatermarks++)
        {
            //Draw the m_Copyright string
            grPhoto.DrawString(strText,     //string of text
                fnt,                        //font
                brush,                      //Brush
                new PointF(x,y),  //How to calculate this Position ?
                StrFormat);
        }
    }
```

Comment: it all depends on how you want your tiles to be arranged: do you need to have the same number of tiles on every line? Do you accept all values of number of tiles? Do they have to be arranged in columns or can there be a decay on every line? ..... there's a lot to answer before trying to calculate these positions

Comment: In my program I want to let the user choose any arrangement, so any example would be helpful, with decays or centered columns.

Comment: do you want your tiles to entirely fill the image? Can or should they be scaled?

Comment: also what have you tried so far? Do you have an idea of how to do this?

Comment: Try to reformulate your question, and be more precise about what you want to do, and how you think you would do it, also tell what exactly are you stuck with. Right now I have the feeling you didn't really think about what you're trying to do, and your question seems to be "can you give me the code to do this?"...

Comment: This code clearly cannot work without an argument that specifies the tile size.  Add one, then it is easy.

Comment: the tile size it's not a problem, I can set a fixed size or automatic based on the image size. The problem is the text position calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see, you have two problems:

1. Get number of rows and columns of texts
2. Calculate size of one text piece

About first problem, it is a bit mathematical. If you have number and you want to split it to rows and columns, you shoud get all divides of this number, than you shoud choose some, multiply them together and it is one dimension. The second dimension is original number divided by this new number. See example:

- We coud split number 60 to 2 * 2 * 3 * 5
- now we choose 2 * 3 = 6 for one dimension
- the second dimension will be 60 / 6 = 10
- our table will be 6 x 10 cells

The second problem is solved by function MeasureString(string s, Font f). It is method of instance of Graphics and return size of string written with this font.

So the final code will look like this:

```
void DrawTextOnImage(Graphics grPhoto, string strText, Font font, Brush b, int num, Size imageSize)
{
    //here we get dividers of our number
    int[] dividers = Dividers(num);
    //for first dimension I've choosen the biggest number, but you can change it
    int CountX = dividers[dividers.Length-1];
    //the secod dimension
    int CountY = num / CountX;

    //size of one text 
    int imageW = (int)grPhoto.MeasureString(strText, font).Width;
    int imageH = (int)grPhoto.MeasureString(strText, font).Height;

    //string format
    StringFormat StrFormat = new StringFormat();
    StrFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

    //now when we knownumber of rows and columns and their size, we can start drawing
    for (int x = 0; x < CountX; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < CountY; y++)
        {
            PointF point = new PointF(      //position you want to know
                (imageSize.Width - CountX * imageW) / 2 + (x * imageW),
                (imageSize.Height - CountY * imageH) / 2 + (y * imageH)
                );
            grPhoto.DrawString(strText,     //string of text
            font,                           //font
            b,                              //Brush
            point,                          //positio
            StrFormat);
        }
    }
}

int[] Dividers(int i)//get all dividers of number i
{
    List<int> dividers = new List<int>();
    while (i > 1)
    {
        int div = NextDivider(i);
        dividers.Add(div);
        i = i / div;
    }
    return dividers.ToArray();
}

int NextDivider(int i)
{
    if (i < 2) return i; //actualy it could be only value 1
    int div = 2;
    while (i % div != 0)
    {
        div++;
    }
    return div;
}
```

PS: Sorry for my english, i'm not native english speeker

Comment: thanks, the text positions are not displayed correctly, but I got the idea and I have modified it to automatically resize the text and draw it to the correct position.